# java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rmi

When I run my Server code through eclipse, I got the following exception:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.RMIInterface
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:413)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
```

I have started the RMI Registry by simply typing "start rmiregistry" in cmd line. A new window opened with the heading "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\rmiregistry.exe". In this path only I have JDK.

All my .class files available in this path : D:\Workspace\Study\bin\com.

Under the com folder I have all three files "RMIInterface, RMIServer,RMIClient".

When I run the Server code from eclipse, I got an above mentioned exception.(i.e.,) RMIInterface not found. But I have it in the same folder.

What else should I do to run the server?

This is my server code:

```
RMIServer serRef = new RMIServer();
try {
    RMIInterface inref = (RMIInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(serRef, 0);
    Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    reg.bind("ServerObj", inref); -------->Exception in this line
} catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: do you have .class files of all three in the same folder?

Comment: Are you getting this when exporting? binding? lookup in the client? or calling the remote method in the client?

Comment: All my .class files are in the same folder. I am getting this error when I try to run the server code. I mean I want to start the server.Is this a correct way to start the RMI server through eclipse?

Comment: I solved finally.Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(); created the problem. Instead of that, LocateRegistry.createRegistry() helped me

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the way you are accessing your interface.

As you said, `Under the com folder I have all three files "RMIInterface, RMIServer,RMIClient".`

If you do have all files in same package/folder then why are you writing `com.RMIInterface`

it should simply be `RMIInterface` because the way you mentioned it would search for another package called `com` in your current `com` package.

I hope you got my point.

**Edit**

While running RMI programs we do need to have rmiregistry running.

You should run `rmiregistry` **before** starting the Server program.

Try to run it from console or CMD in windows.

Try `rmiregistry` or `start rmiregistry` in CMD. While running from CMD we do need to start rmiregistry from same folder/package from where we are running `javac` and `java`. In case of eclipse I guess you should try to run rmiregistry from your com folder.

**Update**

I think uptil now you are trying to start rmiregistry from inside com folder. Just try to start it out of your com folder.

Inspite of 
`D:\Workspace\Study\bin\com>start rmiregistry`

try

`D:\Workspace\Study\bin\start rmiregistry`

Comment: `com.RMIInterface` is the fully qualified name of the class. There is no evidence here that he is 'writing' that at all, and if he did it woudln't be wrong. Downvote.

Comment: But I didn't use com.RMIInterface. Simply I used RMIInterface only.

Comment: @GPS I have started the rmiregistry before starting the server. In cmd prompt I navigate the path to my com folder and gave "start rmiregistry". registry window got opened. After that only I have started my Server program...

Comment: Can you try running the program in CMD ? Like starting the rmiregistry in cmd and then running your server and client programs from cmd?

Comment: @GPS When I try to run from CMD, I start the server a blink happened. I mean a window opened and closed immediatly. The same happened when I run the client program too. No output resulted. I added my server program in the question...

Comment: @Karthik In that I think your rmiregistry is not getting started properly. Because if you are running the command start rmiregistry, it should start a new cmd console and it should remain there unless you don't close it.

Comment: @GPS Sorry to ask more que. But as you said a new cmd console started. I believe that is a rmiregistry. Is that wrong? Can you please suggest the right way to start?

Answer (score 1):

```
Remote Server Error:RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mathInterface
```

The error very simple to solve to be perform following steps:

- For example your java file consider D drive
- Start rmiregistry D drive( example D:\start rmiregistry)then don't start rmiregistry on the other drives, it will yield the above error

(Wherever your file is, start `rmiregistry`)

reference : [java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread (ClassNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531158/java-rmi-serverexception-remoteexception-occurred-in-server-thread)