# Java RMI Client and Server Separate Machines

Tags: java, rmi

I want to edit the RMI hello world example to work with client and server on different machines, but i'm stuck with the unmarshalling return error.

If i run client and server in the same project on Netbeans they work fine but when i split them i edited the try statement on the client side to be:

```
try {
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
    String[] c = registry.list();
    System.out.println(c[0].toString());
    Remote lookup = Naming.lookup("HelloServer");                                             
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("HelloClient exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

without `Remote lookup = Naming.lookup("HelloServer");`, the print command gives "HelloServer" which is correct, but when i create the remote object I'm getting this error:

```
HelloClient exception: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmimain.Hello
```

I've tested the policy and it's working fine, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java RMI - ClassNotFound exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036566/java-rmi-classnotfound-exception)

Comment: lookup() does not 'create the remote object'. It looks it up in the RMI Registry. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: i know that....i want to lookup the object from the registry to create a remote object out of it....well the thing is that even looking up the object is giving me an error....i can't go on before solving that

Comment: I repeat. Registry.lookup() does not create a remote object. Neither do you. The remote object is at the server. What you get from the lookup is a stub, and you don't 'create' anything with it: you just use it.

Comment: okay...but i can't even have the stub...the Naming.lookup() is giving the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client doesn't have the rmimain.Hello class on its CLASSPATH.

Comment: and how can i solve that? i tried to add the Hello interface to the client but it gives the same error, how can i create a classpath of the server class on the client?

Comment: You tried how? Show what you did, in your question. Your last sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've added the interface Hello to the client project, and i've added the rmimain.Hello class to the CLASSPATH environment variable...when i echo %CLASSPATH% it gives:

C:\Users\Nina_2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RMIMain\build\classes\rmimain

Did i do it right? because has nothing changed it still gives the same unmarshalling return error.

Comment: You can't add classes to the CLASSPATH. You can only add directories or JAR files.

Comment: sorry i meant i added the directory which has the rmimain.Hello class

Comment: You shouldn't have done that either. You should have added the directory which contains the directory 'rmimain', that in turn contains 'Hello.class'. You don't seem to have a secure grasp of the CLASSPATH. I suggest you look it up.

Comment: i've added the directory which contains the directory 'rmimain' and i still have the same error...

Comment: problem solved...i've added the jar file of the server project to the library of the client....thanks EJP for your help:)