# How do I implement RMI using the computers connected in the same network?

Tags: java, rmi, rpc

I tried implementing RMI concept using the two computers connected in my company network. I binded the remote object using my ip address and specific port number. Everything worked fine when I tried it in my local machine.

Now In order to access it from the other computer I shared the Adder (extends Remote ) interface .class file with the other computer and a client code. When I tried to access it it throwed the **ClassNotFoundException: stub not found**.

So I shared the **stub.class** file which is generated after running the command   **>> rmic AddImpl**. After that it worked fine on the remote computer also.

Now My question is, Is that how RMI is implemented ? Do we need to share both the Adder interface and the stub class file generated in order for a client to access our remote method ?

Below are My classes and interfaces:

```
interface Adder extends Remote
class AddImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Adder
class Server
class Client
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to share 3 files
Adder.class, Adder.java, AdderRemote_Stub.class (not the java code)

Let us assume you have compiled already

1. create two different directories
2. launch 3 command prompt
3. set first 2 command prompt for the first directory (server)

   Example: c:\rmiserver

   put all files here
4. set last 1 command prompt for the second directory (client)

   Example: c:\rmiclient

   put the client specific files, stub and remote here
5. (optional) set CLASSPATH=. in all command prompt

   this will allow the current directory files to be recognized in CLASSPATH
6. important: run rmiregistry command within the command prompt where the server .class files are in CLASSPATH

   run rmiregistry 5000 command in the any of the first 2 command prompt

   keep it running
7. run your server "java MyServer" in the remaining command prompt of the first 2
8. run you client "java MyClient" in the last command prompt which is a different directory

   if this is is working then your network logic will work

Duplicate [java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread (ClassNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531158/java-rmi-serverexception-remoteexception-occurred-in-server-thread-classnotfou)

Comment: Yes my logic works just fine for network also. I was asking " is that how RMI can be achieved ( by sharing adder , stub files ) ? "

Comment: You don't need to share Adder.java. Two files.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Just wanted to confirm is that how it can be done. Thank you :)

Comment: that is how RMI works using stub and skel, it is a mutual understanding that the machine A and B will have an extra file distributed for communication and object serialization