# java.rmi.UnmarshalException running rmi server code

Tags: java, rmi

I am getting below exception when I run the rmi server code

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.server.test.TestRMIInterface
```

Below are the steps I am following

1. Open command prompt and run `rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false 5000`
2. Run server code as `java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/D:/Test/Code/jartouse/" -jar TestRMIServer.jar`

TestRMIServer.jar has dependency on TestRMIInterface.jar and I have placed the TestRMIInterface.jar in jartouse directory

It works fine if I run the rmi server as given below

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/D:/Test/Code/jartouse/TestRMIInterface.jar" -jar TestRMIServer.jar
```

Not sure what is missing here. Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: Do any of these help to fix or explain what you're observing? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464687/running-rmi-server-classnotfound) and a linked [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531158/java-rmi-serverexception-remoteexception-occurred-in-server-thread-classnotfou)

Comment: Given that you know (2) works, it is hard to see why you are even attempting (1), or asking the question, and unless the directory specified in (1) is the head of a package-structured hierarchy of .class files, there is no reason why it should work at all. It doesn't have anything to do with [tag:Java-ee]: don't tag indiscriminately.